# Revision-2 C++ implementation of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have addressed all your comments in my previous post.
[C++ implementation of a linked list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146357/c-implementation-of-a-linked-list)

Can you please comment on,

1. How efficient the code is?
2. Am i using too much extra variables to implement each functionalities?
3. How can i improve error handling,return codes?

   ```
   class LinkedList{
   public:
      LinkedList():
         head(nullptr),
         tail(nullptr){}
      ~LinkedList(){
         Node *temp;
         while( head!=NULL ) {
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
         }
         tail = NULL;
      }
      /* copy constructor */
      LinkedList(const LinkedList& new_item):
         head(nullptr),
         tail(nullptr){
            Node *temp = new_item.head;
            Node *node;
            if(temp)
               head = node = new Node();
            while(temp != NULL){
               node->item = temp->item;
               if(temp->next) {
                  node->next = new Node();
                  node = node->next;
               } else {
                  tail = node;
               }
               temp = temp->next;
            }
      }
      void InsertFront(int key);       /*Insert a node in head of the list*/
      void InsertBack(int key);        /*Insert a node in end of the list*/
      int TopBack();                  /*Get tail node - complexity-O(1) */
      int TopFront();                 /*Get head node - complexity-O(1) */
      void PopBack();                  /*Remove the first element in list.complexity-O(n)*/
      void PopFront();                 /*Remove the first element in list.complexity-O(1) */
      void DeleteNode(int key);        /*Delete first matching  node of a given key.complexity-O(n)*/
      void PrintList(std::ostream& out);
   private:
      struct Node {
         int item;
         Node *next;
         Node():
            item(-1),
            next(nullptr) {}
         Node(int key):
            item(key),
            next(nullptr) {}
      };
      Node *head;
      Node *tail;
   };

   /*Insert a node in head of the list*/
   void
   LinkedList::InsertFront(int key) {
      Node *node = new Node(key);
      if(!node)
      {
         std::cout << "ERR: Failed to allocate new node \n";
         return;
      }
      if(head != NULL){
         node->next = head;
      } else {
         tail = node;
      }
      head = node;
   }

   /*Insert a node in end of the list*/
   void
   LinkedList::InsertBack(int key) {
      Node *node = new Node(key);
      if(!node)
      {
         std::cout << "ERR: Failed to allocate new node \n";
         return;
      }
      if(!head) {
         head = node;
      } else {
         tail->next = node;
      }
      tail = node;
   }

   /*Get tail node - complexity-O(1) */
   int
   LinkedList::TopBack(){
      if(!tail) {
         std::cout << "ERR: List is empty\n";
         return -1;
      }
      return tail->item;
   }

   /*Get head node - complexity-O(1) */
   int
   LinkedList::TopFront(){
      if(!head) {
         std::cout << "ERR: List is empty\n";
         return -1;
      }
      return head->item;
   }

   /* Remove the first element in list.  complexity-O(n) */
   void
   LinkedList::PopBack(){
      if(!tail){
         std::cout << "ERR: List is empty to PopBack \n";
         return;
      }
      if(head == tail)
      {
         std::cout << "popback item is - " << head->item << "\n";
         delete head;
         head = tail = NULL;
         return;
      }
      Node *temp = head;
      while(temp->next!=tail) {
         temp = temp->next;
      }
      std::cout << "popback item is - " << tail->item << "\n";
      delete tail;
      tail = temp;
      tail->next = NULL;
      return;
   }
   /* Remove the first element in list.  complexity-O(1) */
   void
   LinkedList::PopFront(){
      if(!head){
         std::cout << "ERR: List is empty to Popfront \n";
         return;
      }
      if(head == tail)
         tail = NULL;
      std::cout << "popfront  item is - " << head->item << "\n";
      Node *temp = head;
      head = head->next;
      delete temp;
      return;
   }

   /*Delete first matching  node of a given key*/
   void
   LinkedList::DeleteNode(int key) {
      Node *node,*prev;
      node = head;
      while(node != NULL){
         if(node->item == key)
            break;
         prev = node;
         node = node->next;
      }
      if(node == NULL)
      {
         std::cout << "Item not found in list \n";
         return;
      }
      if(node == head){
         if(node == tail){
            std::cout << " Deleting Node with item " << node->item  << " - only node available in list \n";
            delete node;
            head = tail = NULL;
            return;
         }
         prev = head;
         head = head->next;
         std::cout << " Deleting Node with item " << prev->item  << " - head node of list\n";
         delete prev;
         return;
      }
      if(node == tail){
         prev->next = NULL;
         std::cout << " Deleting Node with item " << tail->item  << " - tail node of list\n";
         delete tail;
         tail = prev;
         return;
      }
      prev->next = node->next;
      std::cout << " Deleting Node with item " << node->item  << " -  middle  node of list\n";
      delete node;
      return;
   }

   /*Print whole list*/
   void
   LinkedList::PrintList(std::ostream& out) {
      Node *temp = head;
       while( temp != NULL ) {
         std::cout << temp->item << "\t";
         temp = temp->next;
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
   }

   /* Test code */
   void
   testlist( LinkedList &new_list ){
      new_list.InsertFront(10);
      new_list.PrintList(std::cout);
      new_list.InsertFront(50);
      new_list.PrintList(std::cout);
      new_list.InsertFront(20);
      new_list.PrintList(std::cout);
      new_list.InsertBack(60);
      new_list.PrintList(std::cout);
   }

   void
   insert_random_nos(LinkedList &new_list){
      int i;
      for(i=133;i>11;i=i-7) {
         new_list.InsertFront(i%23);
      }
   }


   int main() {
      LinkedList new_list;
      new_list.InsertFront(70);
      testlist(new_list);
      insert_random_nos(new_list);
      LinkedList y(new_list);
      new_list.PrintList(std::cout);
      y.PrintList(std::cout);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here are my comments:

1. This is purely cosmetic, but having empty lines here and there between methods could make this code mode readable. It's not too easy on the eyes as is.
2. `tail = NULL;` at the end of the d'tor is not strictly necessary. You don't expect the object to be used after the d'tor has run.
3. `new_item` is not the best parameter name in the copy c'tor. Something like `copied_list` is closer to the truth. Also, would use `copied_item` instead of `temp`.
4. There are all kinds of other minor improvements that could be made in the `Node` and `List` class definitions: have an assignment operator and copy c'tor in Node, and make `item` private, replace `PrintList` with a stream operator, rename `TopBack\TopFront` to `Back\Front` etc. All optional of course.
5. Normally you don't expect collection classes such as this one to start printing messages out. If it fails to allocate a node, or tries to access a non-existent element (or gets a different error), it should throw an exception, not open a conversation.
6. `DeleteNode` can be simplified. If `node == head`, you can just call `PopFront`.

As for your questions - just to state the obvious: `PopBack` could be made more efficient if we used a double linked list.  Variable usage is mentioned in comment 6, and error handling in comment 5.